# "Must Declare the Scalar Variable" error when programatically declaring variables

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, gridview, visual-studio-2012

Here's a head scratcher (for me, at least).

I have a GridView where a user can enter information in the footer for quite a few data fields. In general, they follow this format:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="NewDate" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="10px" Font-Size="Smaller" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You must enter a  valid date (MM/DD/YYYY) before submitting...">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WeekOf","{0:MM/dd}") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The InsertCommand looks like this (generalized):

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table] (WeekOf,User,OtherData)
      VALUES (Convert(Date,@WeekOf,101), @User, @OtherData)">
```

Where @User is controlled by the InsertParameter which is working fine (I know this because it is the exact same as my functional SelectCommand / SelectParameter).

Anyways, since these fields are in the gridview, i cant assign them static InsertParameters because they are in the footer of the GridView, which changes since the number of rows changes (that I know of... any enlightenment on how to do that would be awesome), so I'm trying to programatically declare the variables like [this](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-insert-row-in-GridView-with-SqlDataSource.aspx), however I get a "Must declare the scalar variable "@WeekOf" error. Here's the general idea of my GridView_RowCommand function:

```
 TextBox WeekOfin = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewDate") as TextBox;
 TextBox OtherDatain = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewOtherData") as TextBox;

 SqlParameter WeekOf = new SqlParameter("@WeekOf", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
 WeekOf.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 WeekOf.Value = WeekOfin.Text;
 insertParameters.Add(WeekOf);

 SqlParameter OtherData = new SqlParameter("@OtherData", SqlDbType.Int);
 OtherData.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 OtherData.Value = OtherDatain.Text;
 insertParameters.Add(OtherData);

 SqlDataSource2.Insert();
```

Here's the full pertinent code --

```
        private List<SqlParameter> insertParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    protected void SqlDataSource2_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters.Clear();
        foreach (SqlParameter p in insertParameters)
            e.Command.Parameters.Add(p);

    }

    protected void SalesReportingGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Insert" && Page.IsValid)
        {
            TextBox WeekOfin = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data1in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData1") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data2in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData2") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data3in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData3") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data4in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData4") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data5in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData5") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data6in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData6") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data7in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData7") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data8in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData8") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data9in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData9") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data10in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData10") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data11in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData11") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data12in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData12") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data13in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData13") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data14in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData14") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data15in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData15") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data16in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData16") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data17in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData17") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data18in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData18") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data19in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData19") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data20in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData20") as TextBox;
            TextBox Data21in = SalesReportingGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewData21") as TextBox;

            SqlParameter WeekOf = new SqlParameter("@WeekOf", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
            WeekOf.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            WeekOf.Value = WeekOfin.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(WeekOf);

            SqlParameter Data1 = new SqlParameter("@Data1", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data1.Value = Data1in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data1);

            SqlParameter Data2 = new SqlParameter("@Data2", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data2.Value = Data2in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data2);

            SqlParameter Data3 = new SqlParameter("@Data3", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data3.Value = Data3in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data3);

            SqlParameter Data4 = new SqlParameter("@Data4", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data4.Value = Data4in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data4);

            SqlParameter Data5 = new SqlParameter("@Data5", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data5.Value = Data5in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data5);

            SqlParameter Data6 = new SqlParameter("@Data6", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data6.Value = Data6in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data6);

            SqlParameter Data7 = new SqlParameter("@Data7", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data7.Value = Data7in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data7);

            SqlParameter Data8 = new SqlParameter("@Data8", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data8.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data8.Value = Data8in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data8);

            SqlParameter Data9 = new SqlParameter("@Data9", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data9.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data9.Value = Data9in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data9);

            SqlParameter Data10 = new SqlParameter("@Data10", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data10.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data10.Value = Data10in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data10);

            SqlParameter Data11 = new SqlParameter("@Data11", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data11.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data11.Value = Data11in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data11);

            SqlParameter Data12 = new SqlParameter("@Data12", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data12.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data12.Value = Data12in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data12);

            SqlParameter Data13 = new SqlParameter("@Data13", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data13.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data13.Value = Data13in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data13);

            SqlParameter Data14 = new SqlParameter("@Data14", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data14.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data14.Value = Data14in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data14);

            SqlParameter Data15 = new SqlParameter("@Data15", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data15.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data15.Value = Data15in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data15);

            SqlParameter Data16 = new SqlParameter("@Data16", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data16.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data16.Value = Data16in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data16);

            SqlParameter Data17 = new SqlParameter("@Data17", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data17.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data17.Value = Data17in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data17);

            SqlParameter Data18 = new SqlParameter("@Data18", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data18.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data18.Value = Data18in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data18);

            SqlParameter Data19 = new SqlParameter("@Data19", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data19.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data19.Value = Data19in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data19);

            SqlParameter Data20 = new SqlParameter("@Data20", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data20.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data20.Value = Data20in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data20);

            SqlParameter Data21 = new SqlParameter("@Data21", SqlDbType.Int);
            Data21.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Data21.Value = Data21in.Text;
            insertParameters.Add(Data21);

            SqlDataSource2.Insert();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When you step thru the code.. where does it error.. what exceptions are you trapping .. where are you executing the query..?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @DJKRAZE When I open the site it loads the page normally, however when I try to submit, it gets stuck on SqlDataSource2.Insert(); , with the following Exception Details:"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@WeekOf"."

Comment: can you paste the code i.e clean it up and show one or 2 relevant methods that pertain to the code.. it will be easier to read.. that error means that you did not create a Parameter for WeekOf properly
I would suggest using Parameter.AddWithValues("@WeekOf", WeekOf);

Comment: You add the parameters to `insertParameters`, but where is the parameter collection associated with the SQL command?

Comment: @DJKRAZE -- full pertinent code has been posted

Comment: @HABO -- full pertinent code has been posted

Comment: @digitalfrenchfry as it's not clear from the code in the listing above, can you confirm that you've hooked up the _Inserting event and that it's actually being fired?

Comment: @RobWhite Not sure how to confirm that its actually being fired, I can only assume that it is because the program gets stuck during the Insert function.

Comment: it appears that you are doing the Insert as well as the SQLCommand, Connection, and command.Execute a bit awkward ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example on how to add parameters and follow this as a template I will pasted a bit of code to get you started and you will have to fill in the rest..

**Depending on how you calculate WeekOf I would place or get that value outside of the using statement and pass it in where you are trying to do the Convert(Date,@WeekOf, 101)**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table] WeekOf,User,OtherData)
  VALUES (Convert(Date,@WeekOf,101), @User, @OtherData)"");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekOf", WeekOfin.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", YourUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherData", txtAddress.Text);
    ...
    ...
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
      //MessageDlg.Show(ex.Message); //do what ever kind of logging or error trapping here that you want.. 
    }
    //You will need to explain how you are populating or getting
    // the MM/YY for WeekOf 
    //Personally I would refactor this code it's a bit unorthodox 
}
```